# tracking viewership with envers

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I need to audit all of the access that users make to a spring mvc web app using hibernate.  This includes auditing every time a user views data from an object, even if the user does not make any changes to the object.

I have been researching [hibernate envers](http://envers.jboss.org/) as a potential tool for managing all of the auditing.  I notice that envers tracks all modifications to each of the objects in an application.  This is part of what I need.  But I cannot find any documentation or tutorials about how to extend envers so that I can track viewership of objects in addition to just tracking modifications to objects.

Can anyone explain how I might track viewership of objects in a hibernate / spring application?  Either by extending Envers or by some other tool?

Answer (score 1):

As for Envers, it's not really a tool for such kind of auditing. I think you might be better off by simple inserting an "event-entity" on every user action.

Envers is focused on auditing changes done to entities.